# Why does this question almost not get any views?

Tags: discussion

I only got seven views on question about an idea for new workflow. I spend a lot of time and energy researching and creating the question.
I already looked at a few questions on SO that asked the same thing. It looks like an important factor is the title. I first had:

- Change to Distributed Team, Continious Integration and Continious Delivery

I changed this to:

- Would This Workflow Work For a Distributed Team With CI/CD

Asking questions is not my strong point. I often cannot find things with a search engine others get lot of hits on. I made the question more active, but are there other things I could do to improve it?

---

I removed the link. I already got 31 views. If this is because the link I originally had in this question, or because the change of the title, I do not know. And I got two down votes already.

I will ask the question in one of the other groups. Should I delete the original one?

Comment: If it got more view it would probably get downvotes and close votes. You may want to rethink your question, completely.

Comment: Skimming over that question I think (parts of) it might be a better fit for either [SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [devops.se](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: It's not really a programing question. It looks off topics.. Because it's toobraod , not about programing and opinion based.

Comment: You may want to delete the linked question before more friendly meta friends decide to downvote it further. See [meta-effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: FYI, I didn't mean to delete the **link** to the question, but to **delete the linked question**. It's going to be found anyway and continue to be downvoted. It is simply not a good question for the site, and giving it more exposure is not good for you.

Comment: @yivi I will do that. Just deciding on which of the two sites to post it.

Comment: I wouldn't post it in any site without first reading the rules a couple of times, and probably rework the question quite a bit.

Comment: @yivi Yes, that is what I was planning to do. Because I saw indications I could post and indications I should not.

Comment: I received a Peer Pressure and lost four points. There goes my reputation. ;-) Well, I learned something today.

Comment: By the way I saw questions like that on SO, but they are six years, or more, old.

Comment: @CecilWesterhof, Yes, rules have changed since 6 years ago. Which is why we suggest you read the **current** rules, rather than a snapshot of rules written 6 years ago.

Comment: *"I already looked at a few questions on SO that asked the same thing"* -> So you opened a duplicate on purpose?

Comment: @Renan That is a way to look at it, but that is not the way I see it. There where similarities and I even implemented what I found, but I thought there was still missing something.

Comment: I opened a can of worms: I keep getting downvotes on my old questions. If it keeps going like this I will have a negative score in a few hours.

Comment: @CecilWesterhof It is impossible to get below 1 rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the question may have been off-topic or not up to quality standards and is since deleted, but that does not really answer the question why it was not receiving so many views. For the sake of argument, let's pretend it was a question that should have a home in the Stack Overflow repository.

---

So, why did people not even come to look at it? As per usual several reasons can apply, but in this case I think a specific reason rises above all. Let's face it: Stack Overflow is popular, visited by many people and receiving many questions per day, per hour, per minute. This is probably why you decided to ask your question there too, I mean *"many visitors, many answerers, maximum chance my question gets answered"*, right? Right? Well...

That popularity has a downside: we're all suffering from **Stack Overflow**. As in: too-much-stuff-to-fit. There is such a large number of questions rolling in, finding one that you can *and should* answer by just looking at the page of new questions is madness. There is a partial solution to that problem: the personalised front page which is populated/filtered based on followed and ignored tags you setup for yourself, and a bit of guestimation. This creates a listing of questions which may be more closely tied to your interest and skill. Even then the list of questions can be pretty chaotic, put a tag like "javascript" in there and you'll probably want to setup a pretty big list of ignored tags just to see the forest for the trees.

So there we come to the main point: the tags your question had, or more to the point the tags it did not have, probably made it go under the radar.

This is a site primarily about **programming** problems. If your question has no programming language tag or popular technology tag attached to it... you probably shouldn't expect large scale exposure on Stack Overflow. That does not necessarily imply the question is off-topic by the way. But despite how popular and busy Stack Overflow is, not all questions will find an interested audience.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and extensive answer. And this on an answer that was massively downvoted. It did cost me a few points: but I learned a lot. I should be careful where I post, what title I use and the tags I use. (In this case that was not the problem I think, but it does not hurt to be alert on that.) And you gave even an answer on a question I had not asked yet: how to find questions I can answer, so I can give back. Again: thank you very much.